# Is there a synonym for “day” that can go with “at night”, “at dusk”, “at dawn”?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I need a word (ideally) or phrase that means "daytime" that can be used in a sentence "the event happened at dawn/dusk/night/day"

"The event happened at day", and "The event happened at daytime" don't seem to really sound right.

The key thing here is fitting into a sentence that has the word 'at' in it, because it is going into construction of a sentence on a web site that has to cover these possibilities.

A typical example might be "The battle occurred at night in the rain", or "The battle occurred at day in the mist".   The latter doesn't sound right.

Comment: If you just have to use 'at', I think you might say:  The event started at dawn and stopped at dust/night.

Comment: Strictly things happen 'in daytime', but at a push I don't see why you couldn't say 'at daytime'.

Comment: I find that I want to say "during the daytime" not "at daytime".  I'm hoping for a word that works with 'at' better than that!

Comment: @Josh61 in the case where I need to say "the event happened at day", it didn't start at dawn, it could have started at any time _after_ dawn and before dusk.   This sentence is to differentiate the cases of when it might have started.

Comment: I'm looking for the daytime equivalent of "at night".   "At day"...  neither of these are a specific time (in fact, dawn is the only specific instance - dusk itself is a period)

Comment: Why do you need to use 'at' instead of 'in or during'?

Comment: Because I have a web page rendering this.   The selections of when it might happen are a list, into which this word gets populated.   If there isn't such a word, then I will need to go through extra hoops to create a pleasant expression in all cases.

Comment: At daytime: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=at+daytime+&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cat%20daytime%3B%2Cc0

Comment: At daytime/in daytime/during daytime:https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=at+daytime%2C+in+daytime%2C+during+daytime&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cat%20daytime%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20daytime%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cduring%20daytime%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Josh Yes, 'during the daytime' / 'in the daylight hours' are generally acceptable. English is idiosyncratic, and the distributions of classmates are often amusingly / annoyingly different.

Comment: 'At' requires a definite identifiable point in time, but daytime refers to an elongated period commencing at sunrise and ending at sunset. The concept of a fixed identifiable point in time cannot be used to describe a continuum, therefore there can be no synonym of 'daytime' that also means 'a single identifiable point in time'

Comment: @Marv Mills No. 'Night' etc are also extended periods. English is often idiosyncratic rather than easily analysable.

Comment: @Josh61 It's funny how raw numbers can be used to "prove" wierd things.   Look at this: [at daytime compared to at night](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=at+daytime%2Cin+daytime%2Cduring+daytime%2Cat+night&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cat%20daytime%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20daytime%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cduring%20daytime%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cat%20night%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Hmm true, I had not thought of that. Though my statement does hold true for the special case of 'daytime' it does not extend as a general rule. Thanks for pointing out the now-obvious flaw in my position :)

Comment: @Josh61  The actual sentence has extra "construction".   An example would be be "The battle occurred in the rain at daytime".    Somehow it just doesn't sound right, in the way that "The battle occurred in the mist at night" does!

Comment: You are essentially storing a series of characters. Why can't you store a series of characters that possibility include some spaces?  Then you could store "at dawn" "at dusk" "during the day"  etc.

Comment: The event happened neither **at** night nor dusk or dawn.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about programming (fitting words into rigid code slots), not E L & U.

Comment: The background reason for the question is programming.   The actual question is about finding an English word that sound right in a particular usage - sounds precisely "English Language Usage" to me.

Answer (score 3):

I think that trying to avoid common colloquial usage would only confuse the reader.

*"Most automobile accidents occur **at** night.  Most people work **during** the day."*

Comment: It seems to be right, that this is the case.   Dang :)

Comment: @GreenAsJade A key goal is to communicate with absolute clarity.  A simple, colloquial, journalistic approach is usually a good bet.

Comment: This does not satisfy OP's requirement: 'The key thing here is fitting into a sentence that has the word 'at' in it' and so should be posted as a comment. Or rather, as it repeats other comments, not posted.

Answer (score 3):

There is no normal-sounding *at* phrase, but you might try *in daylight*.

Comment: That's not a bad idea!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to repeat the same preposition you can say "by day and by night".

Comment: But then ... by dawn?